# Do both traps and interrupts give control of the hardware to the CPU

Tags: operating-system, cpu, interrupt

I am very confused whether both traps and interrupts can give control of the hardware to the CPU.

Can someone explain why this won't hold or not?

Comment: The CPU controls all hardware, ultimately.  What exactly do you mean here?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be more accurate to say that both traps and interruptions get processed by an interrupt handler (there's a trap handler and interrupt handler but I think it's the same concept).

The interrupt handler then processes the raised interrupt and attempts to resolve it. With a trap it may be something like a division by 0 and with an interrupt it could be something like the disk finished writing a file.

In some cases the trap may be "intentional" - this is useful if your program requires some resources it doesn't have and wants to request them. It raises an exception (trap) and attempts to initiate a context switch to another process while it waits for its resources (no point in hogging the CPU if it's just waiting).

So as you can see, an interrupt can necessitate hardware control but a trap (context switch) may not necessitate hardware use.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to view a fault/trap/interrupt is as a function call. The operating system sets up a vector of handlers for the different events. When they occur, the CPU calls the appropriate function.

The only oddity is that an interrupt can occur asychronously. Faults and traps occur as the result of the instruction stream.